# How to get real number of Instagram followers instead of 'k' using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I am running into a problem where I get the 'k' abbreviation when scraping the number of Instagram followers instead of the actual number.

```
import requests, os, time, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def insta_info(account_name):
    html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/%s/'%(account_name)) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    data = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'property':'og:description'})
    text = data[0].get('content').split()
    user = '%s %s %s' % (text[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
    followers = text[0]
    following = text[2]
    lst = []
    lst.append(followers)
    lst.append(following)
    return lst

kellz = insta_info(kellz_ocho)
print(kellz)
```

This returns:

```
[14.2k, 608]
```

When I would like it to return:

```
[14241, 608]
```

Is there a way to make this happen? I did not write the code above, rather I found it online and implemented it. Therefore I am not positive exactly how it works. Note, the accounts I want to scrape are public.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: why does `14.2k` == `14241` and not `14200`?

Comment: the true number of followers that kellz_ocho is 14,241. However, on instagram, when you have greater than 9,999 followers it replaces the numbers after the comma with ".k". So whether the person has 14200, 14210, or 14241.. it displays as 14.2k.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given is definitely not the right way to do this. Please do not use it.

As you can see from this link: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ getting users info is super simple. You can even get your access token from here: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/ if you don't want to write the code to authenticate.

Comment: Although this is helpful, I need to do it via a python script because it's an automated process that mixes with something else. Do you have any examples of using the methods in those links with python by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you need to use selenium in combination with BeautifulSoup because in page source there is no such thing you are looking for within `meta` tag; rather, the only available thing is what you have got already. Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ; from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/kellz_ocho/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
driver.quit()

for title in soup.select("._h9luf"):   
    posts = title.select("._fd86t")[0].text
    follower = title.select("._fd86t")[1]['title']
    following = title.select("._fd86t")[2].text
    print("Posts: {}\nFollower: {}\nFollowing: {}".format(posts,follower,following))
```

Result:

```
Posts: 59
Follower: 14,253
Following: 608
```

Btw, the follower status has changed already.

Comment: The class names `._fd86t` `._h9luf`, will change, its randomly generated, try a different username, it will be different.

Comment: @krisrak, really!!! How did you know that? I went through at least 10 names before posting the answer? They look weird but not generated randomly. You are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Basically, the additional code checks for the 'k' and multiplies the remaining section by 1000 if there's a 'k'

```
import requests, os, time, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def insta_info(account_name):
    html = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/%s/'%(account_name)) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    data = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'property':'og:description'})
    text = data[0].get('content').split()
    user = '%s %s %s' % (text[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
    followers = text[0]
    if followers[-1] == 'K':
        followers = int(float(followers[:-1].encode('UTF-8')) * 1000)
    else:
        followers = int(float(followers.encode('UTF-8')))
    following = text[2]
    if following[-1] == 'K':
        following = int(float(following[:-1].encode('UTF-8')) * 1000)
    else:
        following = int(float(following.encode('UTF-8')))
    lst = []
    lst.append(followers)
    lst.append(following)
    return lst

kellz = insta_info(kellz_ocho)
print(kellz)
```